# Convert String array to StringBuilder array

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuilder

Is there any quick way of converting a `String` Array to a `StringBuilder` Array other than using a loop?
Say I have this string array:

```
String[] str = new String[] {"hi","hello"};
```

I need to create a `StringBuilder` array with the same literals.

Comment: stream and map ?

Comment: Do you want a `StringBuilder[]`? Really? What for? If you want the `String[]` to be quickly converted to a single `String` delimited by single whitespaces, do `string sentence = String.join(" ", str);`...

Comment: I think we have an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here. Can you please explain why you want an array of StringBuilders? What problem do you think this will solve?

Comment: *other than using a loop?* - they are incompatible types, so the conversion has to happen element-wise, even if someone else writes the loop for it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic We receive a string array from a previous block of code, and each of  these strings need to be edited according to some business rules before we can display it in a app and we need to pass it as a string array again. You might be correct about the XY problem, but I wanted to make use of the stringbuilder for the ease of editing each strings. Hence this question

Comment: Perhaps using a StringBuilder as one of the stages of conversion is a good idea, but unless the edits are interdependent between the elements, you don't need an array of string builder. You can do a loop that does the conversion, either a declarative loop or a stream. No need to keep the StringBuilders around and loop again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.setAll()` seems to be the simplest one, it may be shorter to type than a loop:

```
    String[] str = new String[] {"hi","hello"};
    StringBuilder[] sbs = new StringBuilder[str.length];
    Arrays.setAll(sbs, i -> new StringBuilder(str[i]));
```

There is even `parallelSetAll()`, but for simply creating objects it would have to be a really long array to profit from parallelism I think.

You won't believe how it looks like on the inside:

```
public static <T> void setAll(T[] array, IntFunction<? extends T> generator) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(generator);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        array[i] = generator.apply(i);
}
```

(The parallel one uses `IntStream.range().parallel().forEach()`)

---

**Original answer**
No loops were harmed during the making of these lines:

```
String[] str = new String[] {"hi","hello"};
StringBuilder[] sbs=Arrays.stream(str)
                          .map(s->new StringBuilder(s))
                          //.collect(Collectors.toList()) // not needed, see comments
                                                          // of @RealSkeptic and @Holger
                          .toArray(StringBuilder[]::new);
```

So yes of course, it can be done without writing the single loop statement. <strike>Just in the background there will be two loops now, one for creating the `StringBuilder`s into a `List`, and one for converting it to an array. And</strike> I still would not call it particularly beautiful <strike>either</strike>, especially when considering that a similar bunch of lines will be there too at the end, for the other direction.

---

If the modifications are independent, and the ends have to stay arrays, I would indeed go with a single, "classic" indexed `for` loop, doing everything in the body:

```
String[] str = new String[] {"hi","hello"};
for(int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str[i]);
  ...magic...
  str[i] = sb.toString(); // or perhaps into a new array
}
```

Comment: In your stream solution, there is no need to collect into a list and then an array. `Stream` has its own `toArray` method which works exactly the same.

Comment: In other words, `StringBuilder[] sbs = Arrays.stream(str).map(StringBuilder::new).toArray(StringBuilder[]::new);` In fact, prior to Java 11, `.toArray(StringBuilder[]::new)` only works with a `Stream`.

Comment: Thanks. *There can be only one* @ per comment, so I just mentioned both of you in the modification and none of you in this very line.